# How to call a Dafny method from a C# main program?

Tags: c#, dafny, netmodules

I need to feed data to Dafny functions and get their output. For that, I am trying to create a C# program that calls the Dafny functions.

As a test I created  a very simple Dafny file:

```
module myDafnyModule {
    method boolMethod(b: bool) returns (r:bool) {
        return !b;
    }

    function method boolFunctionMethod(b:bool):bool {
        !b
    }
}
```

My main guess is that I should approach this as a [multi-file .NET assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/build-multifile-assembly).
For this, I should

1. generate the C# for the Dafny part of the program with something like `dafny /spillTargetCode:1 dafnyModule.dfy`
2. compile that as a module with something like `csc /target:module dafnyModule.cs`
3. compile the main C# program with something like `csc Main.cs /addmodule:dafnyModule.netmodule`.

Step 1 works. However, the `csc` call in step 2 fails with lots of errors like

```sh
$ csc dafnyModule.cs                       
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

dafnyModule.cs(50,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Immutable' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
dafnyModule.cs(1718,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BigInteger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
...
```

**My questions are:**

- What is missing in the `csc` call in step 2 to compile the C# code generated by Dafny?
- Is this the best way to interface with Dafny code? There are other options I could imagine, though they seem more laborious and error-prone:

  - have the main entry point in Dafny and have it call C# functions to deal with the input/output?
  - have a C# program load at runtime the DLL generated by the Dafny compiler?
- Actually, I'm not a C# person and I'd prefer to call into Dafny from Java! But I guess Java support is less mature than C# and there's less information. [A Java similar question got no answers...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103329/compiling-dafny-to-java)

For completeness, I am using Dafny 3.1, dotnet 5.0.104, csc from mono 6.12.0.90 on macOS 11.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the Dafny-generated C# code starts with a handful of lines that seem to hint to use `dotnet` to compile, instead of `csc` (which I was using because `dafny /help` mentions it).

Following that thread I found [how to build an application with a library using `dotnet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code).

And it worked, just by putting the generated C# code where the library is expected and the main app where it should be.

The whole solution & project thing of dotnet sounds kinda daunting and brings painful flashbacks of Visual Studio on Windows, but it was mercifully straightforward.